# Como fazer um find no GNU Linux trazer alguns arquivos e ignorar outros

Tags: linux, shell-script

Como fazer um find no GNU Linux trazer todos arquivos de uma pasta, ignorando os arquivos de um subdiretório especifico.

Answer (score 3):

Se quiser eliminar o diretório "exemplo"

```
find . -path ./exemplo -prune -o -name 'arquivo.html'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.